# Return updated value in getter function of model class in android studio java

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

I am calculating the number of units available base on the units sold in "Sale" table. I am using Firebase Datastore. My code looks like below inside the Post Model

```
public String getUnits() {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sale").child(this.postid);
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Long count = Long.parseLong(units) - snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            units = count.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    return units;
}
```

I need to return the value inside onDataChange(). It is showing exception.

I am trying to get this value inside a Adapter in Android Studio.

```
private void getCardCount( Post post){
  cardCount.setText("Remaining " + post.getUnits());
}
```

If I put return inside onDataChange(), it gives the error : *Cannot return a value from a method with void result type*

and when I change the return type to String, it gives the error: *'onDataChange(DataSnapshot)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener' clashes with 'onDataChange(DataSnapshot)' in 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener'; attempting to use incompatible return type*

I am new to android studio and some help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the exception message you are getting to your question, including the full stack trace.

Comment: You don't show where `units` is defined. Generally speaking, adding a listener to an object does not cause the code within the listener to be called right away.  Are you expecting that `units` will be set by the `onDataChange` method by the time that the `getUnits()` function completes and returns its value?  I don't know the specifics of The Firebase API, but in most cases that look like this code, you can't assume that `units` will change before `getUnits()` returns its value.

Comment: I have edited the question with more details @CryptoFool